# Выключка по ширине ухудшает читаемость?

Tags: оформление-текста, интернет

Голова уже кипит от типографики, но разобраться надо.

В подавляющем большинстве книг на русском языке применяется следующее оформление: выключка текста — по ширине, слова переносятся, вертикально абзацы друг от друга не отбиваются (стандартный межстрочный пробел), зато отбивается красная строка. Выглядит это так:

[image: отцы и дети Тургенев]
Отрывок из начала «Отцы и дети»

Является ли такой метод наиболее эффективным и удобным для чтения или же наоборот — наиболее эффективным в плане экономии места и бумаги?

Но меня больше интересует веб, ведь там ситуация разительно отличается: выключка текста — по левому краю (оставляя правый край рваным), слова не переносятся, красная строка не отбивается, зато отбиваются сами абзацы вертикально.

[image: Тургенев Википедия]
Статья с «Википедии». Ширину колонки намеренно уменьшил для демонстрации.

По личным ощущениям могу сказать, что первый пример пускай и выглядит аккуратнее, даётся с трудом, особенно легко потерять нужную строку при чтении огромных абзацев. У второго тоже есть свои проблемы — рваный правый край выглядит неряшливо и немного, но всё же ухудшает читаемость (частично проблема решается правильной расстановкой неразрывных пробелов, чтобы, например, не отрывать частицы и союзы от зависимых слов). Зато потеряться в строках уже намного сложнее, ведь они все разной длины. А ещё слова не переносятся, что тоже улучшает читаемость, т. к. мы (люди) всё же читаем слова целиком, а не по слогам.

И всё же, как <del>правильно</del> желательно оформлять эссе, рассказы и статьи в цифровом формате (в интернете)?

Comment: Да вы сами почти всё и рассказали. Только вопросы форматирования проблем языка не касаются. Тем более в вебе.